# Events for admin user login/logout in magento?

Tags: magento, events, zend-framework, observers, adminhtml

Is there any events for admin user login and logout in magento?

I found some events for customer login but not for Admin user login

```
<events>
         <customer_login>
           <observers>
              <scommerce_customer_login><!--User Defined Unique Name-->
                 <class>scommerce_login/observer</class>
                 <method>checkLoginStatus</method>             
              </scommerce_customer_login>
           </observers>
         </customer_login>
      </events>
```

For how to get the admin users login events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected

```
<events>
            <admin_session_user_login_success>
                <observers>
                    <Ss_Supportticket_model_observer>
                        <!-- The model to be instantiated -->
                        <class>Ss_Supportticket_model_observer</class>
                        <!-- The method of the class to be called -->
                        <method>saveUserLoginSession</method>
                        <!-- The type of class to instantiate -->
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </Ss_Supportticket_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </admin_session_user_login_success>
            <!-- <controller_action_predispatch> -->
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_logout>
                <observers>
                    <Ss_Supportticket_model_observer>
                        <!-- The model to be instantiated -->
                        <class>Ss_Supportticket_model_observer</class>
                        <!-- The method of the class to be called -->
                        <method>saveUserLogoutSession</method>
                        <!-- The type of class to instantiate -->
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </Ss_Supportticket_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_logout>
            <!-- </controller_action_predispatch> -->
        </events>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you **temporarily** edit Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent to log the $eventName that is passed in, you can log a list of every single event that is dispatched. (Please note that for some actions, this may cause an error due to the large volume of events that are firing, so be sure to remove your logging and avoid doing this in a production environment).

Using this method, I see `admin_session_user_login_success` which seems promising. For logging out, the only ones that seem relevant are `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_logout` and `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_index_logout`, which may or may not be reliable enough indicators for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you're stuck with

```
admin_session_user_login_success
admin_session_user_login_failed
```

for catching admin log in.